# Container Fluid Not Full Width

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3

please take a look at my sample code

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <section class="parallax-bg-1 text-center" style="background-image:url('https://killtheboredomdotcom.files.wordpress.com/2015/08/skyline-of-rome.jpg?w=1920&h=768&crop=1')">
        <h1 class="">Welcome</h1>

        <p class="lead">subtitle</p>
    </section>
</div>
```

the picture is in parallax mode but take a look at the screenshot it still has padding.

[image]

im trying to achieve the same result as this site: http://remtsoy.com/tf_templates/traveler/demo_v1_7/index.html

JS Fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/uf9np3kq/

Comment: make sure your background is filling with the cover property

Comment: JS Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/uf9np3kq/

Comment: There's loads of unneccessary CSS in your JSFiddle. You can include Bootstrap as a resource, and then just show the CSS relating to the issue you need help with.

Answer (score 11):

The default style of `container-fluid` has `padding left and right` of 15px. you can override the default behaviour by applying the following style:

```
.container-fluid{
   padding: 0;
}
```

```css
.container-fluid{
    padding: 0 !important;
}
section.parallax-bg-1{
background-size: cover;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
<section class="parallax-bg-1 text-center" style="background-image:url('https://killtheboredomdotcom.files.wordpress.com/2015/08/skyline-of-rome.jpg?w=1920&h=768&crop=1')">
        <h1 class="">Welcome</h1>

        <p class="lead">subtitle</p>
    </section>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: @Nevi I've updated the answer with your provided code. It's working here.

Comment: its weird i have tried adding .container-fluid{
   padding: 0;
} and .container-fluid{
    padding: 0 !important;
} to all my medias and still not working.

Comment: @Nevi Then it might be the issue with your `background-image`. Did you apply `background-size: cover;` property? Can you share your original code?

Comment: @Nevi This doesn't seem to be your original code. If you change the class `container` to `container-fluid`, the problem in this fiddle is solved :)

Comment: @Nevi Apply `padding: 0;` to your `container-fluid` and a style `section.parallax-bg-1 {
    background-size: cover;
}` to your code. This should solve your problem.

Please check my updated answer.

Comment: i tried doing it, why it doesnt work? im using asp.net mvc btw

Comment: @Nevi Did you wrap your `section` around `row` class ?

Comment: yes look <div class="row">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <section class="parallax-bg-1 text-center" style="background-image:url('https://killtheboredomdotcom.files.wordpress.com/2015/08/skyline-of-rome.jpg?w=1920&h=768&crop=1')">
            <h1 class="">Welcome</h1>

            <p class="lead">subtitle</p>
        </section>
    </div>
</div>

Comment: @Nevi Please check my updated answer. The `row` class should go under `container-fluid`, not before it.

Answer (score 8):

change

```
<div class="container-fluid">
....
</div>
```

To

```
<div class="container-fullwidth">
....
</div>
```

Comment: boostrap-3 doesnt have `container-fullwidth`

Answer (score 1):

You might want to use the div class of jumbotron.

```
<div class="jumbotron">
  <div class="container">
    <h1>Welcome</h1>
    <p>Subtitle>
  </div>
</div>
```

It would look something like this: http://getbootstrap.com/examples/jumbotron/. Then you can apply the styles as you would like.

Answer (score 0):

Just wrap your content in a `div.row`: http://jsfiddle.net/uf9np3kq/1/

Answer (score 0):

Just swap your `<section>` and your `.container-fluid`. Assuming that your section has the background image. See updated fiddle below:

### [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uf9np3kq/3/)

Current:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
  <section>...</section>
</div>
```

Change to:

```
<section>
  <div class="container-fluid">...</div>
</section>
```

Note: This also applies to `.container` not just `.container-fluid`

Answer (score 0):

```html
 <p>if you using vb.net so please go **-Layout.chtml** and find</p>

<div class="container body-content">
        @RenderBody()
        <hr />
        <footer>
            <p>&copy; @DateTime.Now.Year - My ASP.NET Application</p>
        </footer>
    </div>

<p>and change it to the </p>

 <div class="container-fluid">
        <section>
            @RenderBody()
        </section>
    </div>
        <hr />
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <footer>
            <p>&copy; @DateTime.Now.Year - My ASP.NET Application</p>
        </footer>
    </div>

**i hope this method usefull for you..**
```